# A month in advance or for a month in advance?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which variant is correct: a month in advance or for a month in advance?
For example, "She plans her budget (for) a month in advance."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perfect continuous tense with 'for' or without 'for'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14295/perfect-continuous-tense-with-for-or-without-for) Also [Why is a preposition sometimes optional?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21621/) and [Is the preposition 'to' optional in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268252/) and [Preposition before noun phrases - omission of "in"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52831/) and [Is Up after some verbs optional?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246324/) and others.

Comment: ...basically, *I can only stay a minute* and *I can only stay **for** a minute* are exactly equivalent. It's just a stylistic choice whether to include the preposition in such contexts.

Comment: Can "a-budget-for-a-month" also mean "a monthly budget" as in the case of "yearly budget, quarterly budget, etc"? If yes, the sentence can also mean "She plans her budget-for-a-month one month earlier".

Comment: Surely you can only plan a budget (or anything else) in advance, so that 'in advance' becomes redundant or odd. I'd rather say 'she plans her budget a month at a time'.